# CPU usage 99% when reading large txt file using fgets() c++

Tags: c++, text, cpu-usage, fgets

I have to read in large txt files (1Gb) line-by-line, and use fgets() to do so. I run an empty while loop and execution takes extremely long (30mins) with 99% CPU utilization.

int buffer_size = 30;
 char buffer[buffer_size];

```
 while (fgets(buffer, buffer_size, traceFile1) != NULL)
 {
 }
```

I did do some reading and apparently the overheads related to text parsing causes this. So the question is, is there any way to read in a txt file while avoiding this? I'm reading in traces for a network simulator, so each line typically has |Injection_cycle  source  destination|

I've been searching for a while, so if anyone has a smart answer to this I would be absolutely delighted :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: "I did do some reading and apparently the overheads related to text parsing causes this. " - there is no parsing going on in the code you posted.

Comment: It should not take 30 minutes to read a 1GB file this way. Something is very wrong. (The small buffer size doesn't help, but that can't be the whole problem.)

Comment: Thank you all for your time and help! I've varied the file size, and even if the text file is just 1MB, I also get 99% CPU utilization. So it seems like it's unrelated to the text file size. What could it be? I'm running it in eclipse luna 4.4.2 on a mac book pro, gcc compiler.  Really can't figure it out :/

Answer (score 0):

```
1GB = 1024MB= 1048576 KB = 1073741824 B 
30 min = 1800 seconds
```

So you are basically comparing about 595k/s comparisons (checking if the current character is '\n' or '\t' or eof) and making around the same amount of memory assignations. Not just that but also making a jump operation since you have a loop statement.

This while not being too fast it's not too slow either, I've seen a few "critical cases" that are unable to use the computer memory system properly, how does the result scale for various sizes?

I think I'm rather off the reason, but hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!!  I've varied the file size, but even for 1MB I get this utilization behaviour and it takes awfully long :/ Still can't figure out what it is...

Comment: it could possibly be that your buffer size is too small? from what I read in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/   it will only fill the buffer with 30 chars or until it will find a new line character. it only detects the new line character or eof, so that could be the reason, in your average book it's rare to find characters that small, have you tried raising it to 100-200?